# Summing and getting distinct count Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this :

```
ID | Value
1     100
1     300
2     200
3     300
4     400
```

basically i am trying to achieve this :

```
ID Distinct Count | Total Value
4                  1300
```

so u see the total distinct count of ID is 4 and not 5 as 1 is repeated twice.

I did this in python:

```
df = df.aggregate({'Id':lambda x: x.nunique(), 'value': 'sum'});
```

But this gave me a 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

What am i doing wrong?

PS: I also did agg but it didnt work also

Comment: It's `agg`, not aggregate.

Comment: I did that too before it didnt work

Comment: Oops, `agg` is new in 0.20. Upgrade.

Comment: oh but it cant be because my previous code before this is using agg / aggregate and its working fine.

Comment: @Adam - what was your previous code? Maybe `groupby` + `agg` and it is different.

Comment: I previously did a group by when I did agg. Is agg only exclusively for groupby?

Comment: Like I said, they became first class functions in 0.20.

Comment: @Adam - I add solution for oldier version of pandas. Not so nice, but working ;)

Comment: Don't keep using older versions. The best is to update. There are a lot of performance improvements and bug fixes they keep making, so the next version is always better than the last.

Comment: Ah i gt it. have updated it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on an older version of pandas, because [`df.agg`/`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) are introduced as first class functions from `v0.20`. Upgrade with `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

(`v0.20+` answer) If you use the function, you can drop the `lambda`.

```
df.agg({'ID' : 'nunique', 'Value' : 'sum'}).to_frame().T

   ID  Value
0   4   1300
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
df = df.apply({'ID':'nunique', 'Value': 'sum'}).to_frame().T
print (df)
   Value  ID
0   1300   4
```

If oldier version of pandas use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[df['ID'].nunique(), df['Value'].sum()]], 
                    columns=['ID Distinct Count','Total Value'])
print (df)


   ID Distinct Count  Total Value
0                  4         1300
```